# Unable to access OS using start /SP/console eventhough eeprom console=ttya

Tags: solaris

I have a system with solaris 10 update 11. I am trying to access the OS via ILOM using start /SP/console.

When i fire eeprom command in OS I was able to find

console=ttya

When I did a reboot I was able to observe boot screen upto grub menu. After that it just hangs or stops showing anything.

I am able to OS in all the other blades on the same chassis

Is there I can do something other than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the boot menu entry from the grub menu list and append `-B console=ttya` to the kernel line. Then try to boot and see if this gives you the desired result.

To make the change permanent, edit `/rpool/boot/grub/menu.lst` and search for `kernel /platform/i86pc/multiboot`

Append `-B console=ttya` to this line and save the file

Comment: Hi, Is this the way to force it to work. As on other blades of the same chassis i can see there is no console related details present in menu.lst and We are able to boot the OS without Issue. menu.lst is present inside /boot/grub/menu.lst in my setup unable to find anything as /rpool

Comment: That you do not have `/rpool` says that you most probably do not have a ZFS root but using UFS as filesystem. I encountered the same behaviour in the past and setting the `-B console=ttya` worked for me. If you can try if this will work for you, you might have yourself a workaround or else you might open a SR at Oracle to inspect the different behaviour between your systems.